# Imagens em diferentes tipos de ecra

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Neste momento tenho estes layout´s para suportar os diferentes tamanhos de ecra

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando testo a app em dispositivos 4 polegadas ou 4.5 polegadas, ambos vão usar o layout `activity_main.xml` que corresponde ao tamanho normal porem reparo que no dispositivo de 4 polegadas algumas imagens ou texto são cortados porque não cabem no ecrã.

Como é que posso resolver isto?

Comment: Tem de ter em conta que dispositivos com dimensões iguais podem ter densidades diferentes. Além de layouts diferentes para cada dimensão tem de ter imagens dimensionadas para cada densidade.

Comment: @ramaral Exato, entretando acrescentei as pastas `drawable`com os vários tipos de densidade porém eu não sei qual é que é o tamanho que cada imagem tem em cada pasta. Eu tenho uma imagem de 60x70 +- e fica bem em dispositivos `xhdpi` mas quando passo para `hdpi`ja fica mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem de ter em conta que dispositivos com dimensões iguais podem ter densidades diferentes de tela.

O espaço ocupado por uma imagem, relativamente às dimensões da tela, é diferente em cada densidade. Quanto menor a densidade maior é o espaço ocupado.
Para que o espaço ocupado seja igual é necessário disponibilizar imagens dimensionadas para cada uma delas.

Deverá criar na pasta `\res` novas pastas drawable, uma para cada densidade, na forma `drawable-xxx`, onde `xxxx` é:

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi

Os tamanhos das imagens, a incluir em cada uma delas, são calculados em relação à imagem na pasta mdpi.
Use um editor de imagens que permita redimensioná-las, Photoshop por exemplo.

Os factores a usar são:

- ldpi => 0.75
- mdpi => 1
- hdpi => 1.5
- xhdpi => 2
- xxhdpi => 3

Tendo as dimensões da mdpi as outras dimensões são calculadas multiplicando essa dimensão pelo respectivo factor:

```
dimensão-hdpi = dimensão-mdpi * 1.5
```

Quando a dimensão de partida não corresponde à mdpi, divida-a pelo factor correspondente a essa densidade e multiplique pelo factor da densidade para a qual quer calcular as dimensões.

Por exemplo, se tem uma imagem que "fica bem" em `xhdpi`, as dimensões para as outras densidades são calculadas assim:

```
dimensão-xxx = (dimensão-xhdpi / 2) * factor-xxx
```

Comment: No caso de uma imagem legal em `mdpi`, por exemplo, `xhdpi` deve ter o dobro de pixels? Acho que não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @underfilho Sim, é isso mesmo.