# Como fazer diferentes versões de uma imagem para diferentes densidades de tela?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho uma imagem que vai ser colocada dentro do meu app (apenas um exemplo), como posso fazer uma versão `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, etc dela? Sei que devo colocar nas respectivas pastas, mas quando só tenho uma imagem como posso fazer essas diferentes versões?

Comment: Use um editor de imagens(Photoshop) que permita redimensioná-las. Veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182624/2541) as relações de tamanho a usar. Se for icons use o [Image/Vector Asset](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html) do Android Studio.

Comment: Tem sempre também o [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) como alternativa open source na area de edição de imagem

Comment: Usei o GIMP mesmo, Isac, deu certo aqui. A propósito, @ramaral, se quiser responder posso marcar como respondida.

Comment: Julgo que o melhor é considerá-la duplicata.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o [download de um programinha chamado Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer), ele é um .jar que redimensiona as imagens pra você para os tamanhos do Android. Normalmente a gente gera a imagem com o maior tamanho `xxxhdi` e redimensionamos para os tamanhos menores, isso evita distorção.

Mas a melhor opção mesmo é gerar as imagens vetoriais e utilizando o Android Studio > Vector Asset. Ele gera pra você uns XMLs com as dimensões das imagens para todos os tamanhos. Isso faz com que diminua o tamanho do seu projeto.

Comment: Já consegui fazer com o que o ramaral indicou, mas vou testar a ferramenta também